# Unable to save new databse item with foreignkey

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an issue with Django app.
I have a form to add new Category and the other one to add Subcategory.
Subcategory has a foreignkey to Category, you can find models.py below:

models.py

```
    nom = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)


class SousCategorie(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I have a form to create new Subcategory item in forms.py

```
    nom = forms.CharField()
    categorie = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categorie.objects.all())
    description = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = SousCategorie
        fields = ['nom', 'categorie', 'description']
```

Problem is I use a queryset to make a list with all category items but when I want to save my item, it says that cannot assign queryset because it has to be a category instance:

views.py

```
    form = SousCategorieForm(request.POST)

    nom = request.POST["nom"]
    categorie = request.POST["categorie"]
    description = request.POST["description"]

    souscategorie = form.save(commit=False)
    souscategorie.nom = nom
    souscategorie.categorie = categorie
    souscategorie.description = description
    souscategorie.save()
```

And the error :

> Cannot assign "]>": "SousCategorie.categorie" must be a "Categorie" instance.

Can you help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`ModelMultipleChoiceField` isn't the right choice to `ForeignKey`.
Use `ModelChoiceField` instead.
Detailed information at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships